# jQuery tab activater using URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i need to activate tab which one was called on the url like newandevent.php?tab=tab1 i use the code below it wont work

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,            
            heightStyle : "content",
            create: function(event, ui) { 
                $("#accordion").show(); 
            }
        });

        $('#accordion').activate('option', 'active', $("#<?=$_GET['tab']?>"));
    });
</script>


<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="tab1">title</h3>
    <div>Some text</div>

    <h3 id="tab2">title</h3>
    <div>Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the method is from the accordion widget so you have to call it like `$('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', index)`, then you need to pass the index of the active item

```
$('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', $("#<?=$_GET['tab']?>").index('#accordion > h3'));
```